# Was an old question of mine incorrectly marked as duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I just saw an old question of mine - [Change cursor to hourglass/wait/busy cursor and back in Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13495283/change-cursor-to-hourglass-wait-busy-cursor-and-back-in-qt), which was marked as duplicate of [Qt - change cursor to hourglass and disable cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6580226/qt-change-cursor-to-hourglass-and-disable-cursor)

However, my question is about making an hourglass cursor and then returning from it, without disabling the cursor, the other question is about disabling the cursor - even in his question, he has already solved the first part, so he is not really asking about changing the cursor into an hourglass.

I wasn't really sure if this qualifies as a duplicate, since he is asking about disabling the cursor, I ask about making it hourglass and back, while he doesn't ask about going back from hourglass.

Would it be OK to mark my question for reopening? At the time it was closed, there was no option to mark for reopening.

Comment: You are not actually asking anything specific in your question nor do you show some context. I don't find it fleshed out enough to keep it open.

Comment: I disagree with @juergend here and agree it's not a dupe. Voting to reopen.

Comment: @juergend Sorry, I didn't quite understand that.

Comment: Well, that other question contains your question and the answer to it. So the real problem might be that that question contains two questions (set cursor *and* disable cursor). Though, I'd leave it in place as is now, as I it is a duplicate.

Comment: @TimeTravelingBobby Yes, as I remember, I had seen that question before asking mine, I quickly skimmed through its answers, didn't see an answer to my question, and asked a new one. I didn't expect the answer to be in the question itself. My question also asks about returning from the hourglass cursor, and his does not. Basically, my question asks about A and B, his about A and C, and contains the answer of A in the body of the question, but not in the answers.

Comment: Problem is - both questions have pretty similar titles, and the other one's title is probably a bit inaccurate (suggesting he is asking something, when he already know it). That's why accurate and meaningful titles are so important.

Comment: @Mołot Yes, and now if someone goes to my question, will see the duplicate, and search for the answer to my question there, and not find it, unless he sees the answer in the question itself.

Comment: Done, your question is now reopened.